# Rails: Find by related model attribute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So, I tried to search for an example of how to do this, and I'm not sure I even know how to describe what I'm trying to do. I'm an utter noob when it comes to SQL, and I'm sure this is really basic but I'm totally lost:

I have a model, `Photo`, which `has_many :tags, :through => :taggings`. Tags have a name and an id.

I want to do something like: `Photo.where( #tag_name in [array] )`

... but like I said I have no idea how to write something like that, or what to search to see an example on Google.

Can anyone give me an example of that kind of query, and what it might be called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as a twist on Brett's method, it turns out the following works *without* breaking PostgreSQL:

```
def self.tagged_with( string )
  array = string.split(',').map{ |s| s.lstrip }
  select('distinct photos.*').joins(:tags).where('tags.name' => array )
end
```

Problem solved! See [this article](http://awesomeful.net/posts/72-postgresql-s-group-by) for a great explanation as to why this is a better idea than 'group'.

Comment: Warning: The article link is now redirecting to an advertising page: http://www.awesomeful.net/

Answer (score 10):

Just tried this on a similar model of my own and seemed to work fine:

```
Photo.joins(:tags).where('tags.name' => ['herp','derp']).group(:id)
```

Also, here's a great resource on the [AREL querying interface rails 3 uses](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface), with information on these and other ActiveRecord calls related to querying.

Comment: Awesome. Two questions: 1- Does this kind of query have a name? 2- What is .group(:id) doing?

Comment: This is an inner join (activeRecord figures out how to join across the taggings table automatically because you're using `has_many :through`)  on tags, the where clause determines which records to return.  In my local db, a photo can have multiple tags.  If a photo is tagged `herp` and also `derp` then this query (without `.group`) will return two identical copies of the same Photo (because it matches twice).  Group by id groups the results uniquely based on id - which since you are querying on Photo, assumes the id of the photo table.

Comment: One note of warning to others who may use this, this method broke PostgreSQL when I deployed it to Heroku (because of the `.group(:id)` method). I'll post a solution when I find one.